# Parse findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock error part not working

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

in my parse table there are columns. location and country. and if it is true data will load to the application.but the problem is, its never going to else part in 
`findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` even `wherekeys` wrong. always print out `This section calling` line.

```
 var findLiveFeedData:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Spreads")
        findLiveFeedData.whereKey("location", equalTo: city)
        findLiveFeedData.whereKey("country", equalTo: country)


        findLiveFeedData.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
            (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?)->Void in

            if error == nil{
                if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                for object in objects{
                    self.LiveFeedData.addObject(object)
                    }
                }
                println("This section calling")
                let array:NSArray = self.LiveFeedData.reverseObjectEnumerator().allObjects
                self.LiveFeedData = NSMutableArray(array: array)

                self.tableView.reloadData()

            }else{
                println("Error") // This section never gets called

            }
        }
```

Comment: What error are you expecting?  Are you specifying an invalid key (such as `loc` instead of `location`?) or simply a non-matching key value.  An error won't be returned simply because there are 0 matches

Comment: Just non-matching key value. i mean wherekey location and country not true. it should print `Error` part.

Comment: No, no matches is not an error.  It will simply return an empty array (`objects.count == 0`)

Comment: then i should make condition for `(objects.count == 0)` right? got it

Comment: Or simply `if(objects)` @CadeLewis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you make a query with the wrong key it won't return an error, it will return an array with 0 entries. So the way to find out if nothing has been found it to use:

```
if objects != nil {
    if objects!.count > 0 {
        //You are safe to use the array
    } else {
        //Nothing was returned
    }
}
```